# Keras model is outputting 0 repeatedly with no error

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, face-recognition

I have been working on using a Keras model with a `cv2` face detection script to make facial recognition. I recently ran into a problem where the model outputs a 0 whenever it makes a prediction. This is especially weird because 0 was not in the labels array. By the way, I have a directory called `opencvtrainer` which contains 3 more directories which each contains images of people's faces. Here is the code:

```
import PIL as PIL
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv2
import os
# goes to opencvtrainer directory
basedir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
imagedir = os.path.join(basedir, "opencvtrainer")
ylabels = []
# if directory person: id
labelids = {
    "john_": 001,
    "erin_": 002,
    "scott_": 003,
    "colin_": 004
}
''' "glenn_": 004,
   "faith_": 005,
'''

xtrain = []
xl = []
# make general face classifier
# creates AI needing training
# goes through files in files in the opencvtrainer directory
fc = cv2.CascadeClassifier("lib/python2.7/site-package\
s/cv2/data/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml")
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(imagedir):
    for file in files:
        if "png" in file:
            # path to file
            path = os.path.join(root, file)

            # whose file it is
            label = os.path.basename(root)

            # gets image
            imagep = PIL.Image.open(path)

            # convets image into greyscale then numpy array
            imagear = np.array(imagep.convert("L"), "uint8")
            imagearre = imagear
            face = fc.detectMultiScale(imagearre)

            for (x, y, w, h) in face:
                # makes roi for face
                roi = imagearre[y:y + h, x:x + w]
                roi = cv2.resize(roi, (70, 70))
                # gives that np array to xtrain
                xtrain.append(roi)
                print(roi.shape)
                # gives ylabels a num for all files it opened
                xl.append(labelids[label])


xtrain = np.array(xtrain)
ylabels = np.array(xl)
#adds AI from keras
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
# tells what an input should be & does crap w/ current input
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(70, 70)))
# adds layer
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
# adds layer
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
# adds layer
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.softmax))
# tests for accuracy
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics= . 
['accuracy'])
print(ylabels)
model.fit(xtrain, ylabels, epochs=3)
model.save("test11")'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Change the number of units in the last layer to 4 (since you have 4 different classes):

```
tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
```

2) Start numbering the labels from zero, not one:

```
labelids = {"john_": 0, "erin_": 1, "scott_": 2, "colin_": 3}
```

3) Use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` as the loss function. Alternatively, you can one-hot encode the labels and then use `categorical_crossentropy` as the loss function.